# Microsoft Graph Api doesn't return active subscriptions (since 20.05)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are using the Microsoft notifications service to get notified when a user receives a new message in their inbox. 
In some period we renew the subscription for an active user of the app or if the graph api doesn't return any active subscriptions for the user we create a new one.
Currently, we are getting notified for the new messages, but we noticed that a lot of users have more than one active subscription for the same resource - "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages", and we get notified a couple of times for the same message.

I checked my personal account, that it has active subscriptions, by checking our log files.
I'm getting notified, for example, 6 types for every new message.

When i use the Microsoft Graph explorer to check my subscriptions by calling:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
```

I get an empty string.
But if i use a subscription id from our logs like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/a00022ef-55a4-459f-a53d-c1ca29500000 (this is not real id)
```

it returns the subscription information and I can see that it is still valid.

Does anybody else have this issue? This is a really big issue for our application, so i will be grateful if someone from the Microsoft team checks it out!

Comment: Confirming this issue: I have this exact configuration on a daemon application and am experiencing the same issue. It is unfortunately impacting several primary processes. Side note: I can create a new subscription on the application successfully, but cannot retrieve that subscription at all. Info: I am using the ASP.NET Graph SDK, version 1.15.0

Comment: There is also a bug report you can subscribe for here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4644

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for pointing that out.